# Is it possible to create a multi level (stacked) donut chart with variable diameter on the last stack

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to create a spider chart or sunburst or stacked doughnut chart in Highcharts or another charting library that has fixed width on the outer level and variable length similar to this one:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b13tj46svjpxrku/image.png?dl=0

To confirm, I need to indicate the last data set visually by length so if one bar is 5 a and one is 10 then the second bar is twice as long.

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to your question. Otherwise it may be impossible to tell exactly where the issue lies.

Comment: Hi @Bob Fleming, That chart type is not supported by default in Highcharts. You can try to combine two charts: `column` series in `polar` chart and `sunburst`. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sgvoxf37/

Comment: @ppotaczek that is great. I think this is just what we need. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bob Fleming, I added the suggestion as an answer. If it was helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chart type is not supported by default in Highcharts, but you can combine two charts: `column` series in `polar` chart and `sunburst`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column',
        ...
    },
    ...
});


Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: "sunburst",
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sgvoxf37/